# Django - Select from JSONField

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model with JSONField:

```
class SDReport(models.Model):
    summary = models.JSONField()
```

`summary` field data example:

```
{
    "1": {
        "stm": {
            "1": []
        },
        "non_stm": {
            "1": ["3419250", "3205437"]
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "stm": {
            "1": []
        }
    }
}
```

How can select data (expected result `["3419250", "3205437"]`, default value - `[]`) from path `'1' > non_stm > '1'` with ORM?

UPD. This works:

```
SDReport.objects.annotate(lst=RawSQL("(summary->'1'->'non_stm'->>'1')", ())).first()
```

But `lst` is a string. Is it possible to convert it from string to list in query?

Comment: Almost. I'm updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you treat this as a standard python dictionary?

`summary["1"]["non_stm"]["1"]` will return: `["3419250", "3205437"]`

if it's not a dictionary and just a string of text, try the JSON standard library (`import json`), first calling:
`dictionary = JSON.loads(stringVersionOfDictionary)`

Comment: The example above is just example. Real data are much more bigger and fetching them takes long time.